# line bundle descends?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let the permutation group $S_4$ act on $\mathbb C^4$ by permuting the coordinates. Consider the categorical quotient $\mathbb P(\mathbb C^4)/S_4$. It is a projective variety by a theorem of Mumford. Does the line bundle $\mathcal O(1)^{\otimes 12}$ on $\mathbb P(\mathbb C^4)$ descend to the quotient $\mathbb P(\mathbb C^4)/S_4$ ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, and the good news are that there isn't anything to compute. By a  result of Kempf   a line bundle $L$ on $\mathbb{P}^3$ descends to the quotient if and only if the stabilizer $S_x$ of each point $x\in \mathbb{P}^3$ acts trivially on the fiber $L_x$. Now $S_4$ acts  on $\mathcal{O}(1)$, and $S_x$ act on $\mathcal{O}(1)_x$ through a character $\chi _x:S_x\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^*$, and on $\mathcal{O}(1)^{\otimes k}$ through the character $\chi _x^{k}$.  The abelian subquotients of $S_4$ have order $2,3$ or $4$, hence taking $k=12$ kills all the characters, and therefore $\mathcal{O}(1)^{\otimes 12}$ descends.

Comment: The statement "By a  result of Kempf   a line bundle $L$ on $\mathbb{P}^3$ descends to the quotient if and only if the stabilizer $S_x$ of each point $x\in \mathbb{P}^3$ acts trivially on the fiber $L_x$." is not very precise. You probably mean : an *equivariant* line bundle, else the action on the fiber is not even defined. Could you give a reference ?

Comment: Yes, of course, I meant an equivariant line bundle. A good reference is Theorem 2.3 in the paper of Drezet and Narasimhan, *Groupe de Picard des variétés de modules de fibrés semi-stables sur les courbes algébriques*, Invent. math. 97 (1989), 53-94.

Comment: I think the same proof will work for any $k$ a multiple of $2,3,...,n$ with the action of $S_n$ on $\mathbb P^{n-1}$.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @abx What do you mean by abelian subquotient here ? Again, is the descent unique ?

Comment: @Karthik: abelian subquotient = abelian quotient of a subgroup. And yes, there is a bijection between line bundles on the quotient and equivariant line bundles on $\Bbb{P}^3$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Ok, its unique. Could you please give me a reference where the bijection is given for $\mathbb P^n$ ?

Comment: What's special about $\Bbb{P}^n$? The Drezet-Narasimhan paper gives everything in general.

Comment: Just a small clarification. An equivariant line bundle may not always descent to the quotient. Then what do you mean by there is a bijection between line bundles on the quotient and equivariant line bundles on the projective space ? The paper is in french, so I could not read the proof of theorem 2.3.

Comment: I gave the precise condition in my answer, please read it.