# Descent of line bundles to the quotient

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

If a finite group acts $G$ on a variety $X$, consider the quotient $X/G$. I would like to understand which line bundle on $X$ descends to $X/G$. The action is not free. Can anyone direct me to some reference?

Comment: This may depend on your definition of the word "descend". If you want the original bundle to be $p^*(\text{line bundle})$, where $p\colon X\to X/G$ is the projection, the question reduces to whether $w_1$ (real bundles) or $c_1$ (complex bundles) is in the image of the appropriate induced homomorphism $p^*$. The latter, of course, depends on the action :)

Comment: Cross posted from MSE: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1715532/12885

Comment: See my answer to [this MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/194955/line-bundle-descends?rq=1): a line bundle $L$ (or, more generally, a vector bundle) descends if and only if $L$ admits a $G$-linearization such that the stabilizer $G_x$ of each point $x$ acts trivially on $L_x$.

Comment: @abx what you claim is fine for tame actions but may fail in positive characteristic. See the fantastic post of David Rydh : http://mathoverflow.net/questions/204701/do-line-bundles-descend-to-coarse-moduli-spaces-of-artin-stacks-with-finite-iner/206117#206117

Comment: Mumford talks about this extensively for abelian varieties in his book of the same name.

Comment: Oops! Of course I was assuming characteristic zero, I am a complex man...