# Vector bundles on quotient variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, geometric-invariant-theory

Let an algebraic group $G$ act on a complex variety $X$ such that there is a good enough quotient $X/G$ (for example, $G$ acts on a vector space $V$ linearly and $X=V_{ss}$ is a variety of semi-stable points). Let $E$ be a vector bundle on $X$ with a $G$-action commuting with the $G$-action on $X$. I believe that if $G$ acts effectively then there is a quotient vector bundle $E/G$ on $X/G$. Is it true? Could you give me references? Also, does all line bundles on $X/G$ arise this way?

Comment: No, this is false. You need that the stabilizer of a closed point $x$ acts trivially on $E_x$. For a precise statement, see §2 of Drézet-Narasimhan *Groupe de Picard des variétés de modules de faisceaux semi-stables sur les courbes algébriques*,  Invent. Math. 97 (1989), 53-94.

Comment: @abx Seems like you could just add that as an answer.

Comment: @abx, thank you, and add this as an answer, please.

Comment: related : http://mathoverflow.net/questions/194955/line-bundle-descends, where @abx gives the same answer

Comment: Related: [MSE:1990550](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1538561/vector-bundles-on-m-g/#1990550), there is a link to an article by Knop, Kraft, Vust with very clear explanation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I put my comment as an answer: the necessary and sufficient condition for $E$ to be the pull back of a vector bundle on $X/G$ is that the stabilizer of any closed point $x$ with a closed orbit 
 acts trivially on $E$. This is a lemma of Kempf, well explained in §2 of Drézet-Narasimhan *Groupe de Picard des variétés de modules de faisceaux semi-stables sur les courbes algébriques*, Invent. Math. 97 (1989), 53-94.